# Heavy omnidirectional platform suspension

Tags: mobile-robot, wheeled-robot, design, mechanism, rocker-bogie

I'm planning to build an omnidirectional platform that will support about 180kg robotic arm. The platform will be equipped in meccanum wheels. I would like to have some kind of suspension to avoid wheels loosing contact with the floor on small bumps (let's say 2cm).

The first suspension type I thought about was rocker bogie type, but I'm afraid, that changes of arm center of mass during its movement will introduce too much stress on rocker bogie mechanism.

What other choices would you recommend? Or maybe rocker bogie will be fine after all?